# Declaring a string variable to a Textblock in Windows Metro

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I might be a bit stupid asking this question. But i have not found anything on the net as of yet with my problem. I have a windows app, a listview displaying Texblocks with names in them and is loaded from a xml file. Here is the xaml code.

```xml
<ListView x:Name="listMyLoans" RenderTransformOrigin="0.446,0.54" 
                               Margin="10,150,1052,10" 
                               SelectionChanged="listMyLoans_SelectionChanged_1" 
                               Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="300" Height="100" >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTitle" Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="tbMediaIndex" Text="{Binding MediaIndex}" 
                                                     Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

and I need to declare it like to so in code behind.
string strMediaIndex = tbMediaIndex.Text;

Something like this but does not work, somehow does not see the TextBlock at all.

Thanks

Comment: There are a couple of things you can do, namely parsing the visual tree. This is really not ideal though. What is the scenario you're trying to implement?

Comment: Do you want to get the tbMediaIndex.Text for the selected item in the ListBox?

Comment: The scenario is pretty simple, i have a list of book titles which a user has on loan, when the user clicks one of the items in the list, the app retrieves the tbMediaIndex from the selected item from the list and sends off to the database and pulls all the books information from the database, back to the app. it is simple concept, but i am new to Windows store apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tag property, so you dont have to declare two textbox.
Add a new eventhandler to this textbox OnTapped.

And in the Eventhandler you can cast the sender into textBox. When you cast it, you can grab the Tag element and you are ready. Simple and elegant if you are want to use the code-behind.